# mix two files htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need the specialists' help.

I am trying to mix two files htaccess

The first:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
<FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
ForceType text/html
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddType text/html .gz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gz$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control 'max-age=300, must-revalidate'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html A300
</IfModule>
```

The second:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
```

The first file is used by the plugin wp-supercache (worpress)

I would like that

```
image files Cache-Control = 2592000  
files as css e js Cache-Control = 604800  
files htm had Cache-Control = 43200
```

But it would like not to lose the functionalities of the plugin and for this reason I ask for help.

Thank you very much and excuse my English

Vera

Comment: Found a solution yet? Please see my answer if you're still having problems, it may be because of a missing module in Apache2.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you're missing the `headers` module in Apache (I assume Apache2 in the following, but syntax should be near similar). This works on my machine (without headers module loaded):

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
<FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
ForceType text/html
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddType text/html .gz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gz$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control 'max-age=300, must-revalidate'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html A300
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>    
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

To enable the `headers` module in Apache2:

```
a2endmod headers
apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: I tried to insert this at the and of file but did not work:

    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>

Vera

Comment: I've updated my post because I found it was because of missing headers module in Apache2 (at least on my installation).

Comment: Sune
Thank you for the answer, I was on vacation and had not read your answer.  
The found solution was to use mod_deflate with FilesMatch